# Assigning object type to array value in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm learning Typescript and I discovered that I can do the following without the compiler screaming at me:

```
let obj: object;
obj = [1, 3];
```

If I try to assign `obj` to a string value I get a compiler error:

```
let obj: object;
obj = "[1, 3]";
```

I understand that in javascript everything is essentially objects, including arrays, but in Typescript this behaviour is disappointing to me. I would expect a clear distinction between objects and arrays. Am I missing something obvious and can someone reiterate on the reason for this limitation?

Comment: [`object`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#object) (not `Object`) is a special type for non-primitives.

Comment: Why would you want to assign an object to a variable without having any checks in place for what properties that object would have? It seems like trying to use the type system but quitting not even halfway through. If you want `obj` to hold some object, you'd likely be using an interface for what shape that object would take. Thus you'd not only filter out arrays but also the infinitely many other objects that exist and don't match the interface.

Comment: @VLAZ I see what you mean. I most likely would not use it. But I could easily see someone trying to refactor a js codebase to typescript being too lazy to clarify all of the properties of the object itself and I'm disappointed that Typescript is not catching this.

Comment: @ford04 thanks. So this typecheck is only intended for if you do something generic on an object that could be any object, such as `Object.create({ ...someObject... });`. Makes sense. Sort of. But still feel like the syntax could easily mislead someone to use it in a wrong way.

Comment: Then I can only suggest not being lazy? Because that's a pretty weak argument to me - if somebody can misuse a tool because they don't care how to use it properly...is that the tool's fault? We can easily extend that to *anything* - what if somebody makes a `for` loop that's infinite because they were too lazy to change the counter? Or what if somebody writes a `sort` function that literally just returns the input every time because they were too lazy to implement it? There is probably some type gymnastics you can do to avoid this problem but if somebody is lazy, I doubt they'd care enough.